# QGIS: clip raster by mask with .xyz?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have a DEM in .xyz format and a polygon. I tried to use the "Clip raster by mask" tool to Clip the raster but it doesn't work. The error message just said "couldn't create layer ... there are more Information about the algorithm in the Qgis main Window".

Could it be that clip raster by mask doesn't work with .xyz Format? Any other ideas where the Problem might be?

The CRS is the same for both the Polygon and the .xyz DEM.

Comment: Did you change the output type from the default `[Save to temporary file]`? If not, try saving to a permanent file. If you did, make sure you used an actual file path, not just a file name. It might require a file path without any spaces.